# ObservableCollection throw exception when load second time

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection that when i load data into it one time
and when i load again it thorws an exception the object is not set on reference

```
using (PricingManagerEntities db = new PricingManagerEntities())
                    {
                        m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.Groups = new ObservableCollection<sp_GetGroups_Result>(db.sp_GetGroups(null, true));
                    }
                    return m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel;
```

I did the follwing:

1. spilt the line into servel lines:

   ```
   var a = db.sp_GetGroups(null, true).ToList();
   b = new ObservableCollection<sp_GetGroups_Result>(a);
   m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.Groups = b;
   ```

   and notice that it throws when: 
   m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.Groups  = b;

I tried to clear the Groups try to remove the items, but i always getting 
System.NullReferenceException

the first time I initialize the Groups the Groups is null, and getting 2 records
then i select one of the groups via combobox
and exit the window, next i enter again and it throws me.

here's the combobox xaml:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200"  Name="cmbGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Height="30" DisplayMemberPath="GroupName" SelectionChanged="cmbGroup_changed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
```

here's when selection changed:

```
private void cmbGroup_changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        long groupID = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedValue as sp_GetGroups_Result).GroupID;
        m_engine.GetItemsByGroupID(groupID);
    }
internal void GetItemsByGroupID(long groupID)
    {
        if (m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.Items == null)
            m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.Items = new ObservableCollection<sp_GetItems_Result>();

        m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.Items.Clear();
        using (PricingManagerEntities db = new PricingManagerEntities())
        {
            List<ItemsInGroups> groups = db.ItemsInGroups.Where(iig => iig.GroupID == groupID).ToList();
            foreach(ItemsInGroups group in groups)
            {
                var temp = db.sp_GetItems(group.ItemID, true).FirstOrDefault();
                if(temp != null)
                    m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.Items.Add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put debug point on m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.Groups. Check if m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel is null or Groups is null.

Comment: did that, they are not null

Comment: Where are you initializing List<ItemsInGroups> groups = new List<ItemsInGroups>() ?

Comment: db.ItemsInGroups.Where(iig => iig.GroupID == groupID).ToList(); is from EntityFramework which get all records with the same groupid and transfer them into a list if it's null, the list has no objects.